# Using a variable in different forms

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a variable called `AUTO` in `Form1` and i want to use it in a form called `RoomStack`.

I declared this in `RoomStack.h`:

```
static Form1 ^FM = gcnew Form1();
```

(so afterwards i'll write something like `FM->AUTO`)

But the declaration is giving errors:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '^'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C3845: 'myUI::RoomStack::FM': only static data members can be initialized inside a ref class or value type
```

Note that i encountered this issue before and the same method worked.
I had a form called `NewGame`, it contained a variable that i wanted to use in `Form1`, so in `Form1.h` i declared:

```
static NewGame ^NG = gcnew NewGame();
```

and it compiled.

Why am i having errors now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Form1.h` should be included in `RoomStack.h`

i.e adding the following line in `RoomStack.h` solves the problem:

`#include "Form1.h"`